# What's the math behind Noise Texture Node?

Tags: texturing, materials, shader-nodes, procedural, mathematics

Could you please explain or share sites which explain the intuition of Noise Texture Node? The only helpful source that I can find at the moment is [this video](https://youtu.be/ZjlwnteEzX4). I don't know how to read codes so Blender's source codes don't help.

Thank you so much!

Comment: I've found this quite helpful. https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLRqwX-V7Uu6bgPNQAdxQZpJuJCjeOr7VD - It's not specific to Blender, but more general/fundamental regarding Perlin noise.

Comment: @michaelh Woah, what a gold mine. Thank you!